# MySQL Query Optimization, Primary Key Index is not used?

Tags: mysql, database

We have lot of question like this, but each query is unique so this question arise. I have following query

```
Select * from tblretailerusers where (company_id=169 or company_id in (select id from tblretailercompany where multi_ret_id='169')) and ( id in (Select contact_person_1 from tbllocations where status=1 and (retailer_comp_id=169 or retailer_comp_id in (select id from tblretailercompany where multi_ret_id='169'))) OR id in(Select contact_person_2 from tbllocations where status=1 and (retailer_comp_id=169 or retailer_comp_id in (select id from tblretailercompany where multi_ret_id='169'))) ) and (last_login is not null )
```

It has three tables involve, Retailer, their Location and their User. Standard User information. Each retailer can have child Retailer, so Retailer table has Parent Retailer ID. Currently each table has about 6K records, and all table has Primary key as Auto increment and as I know they are indexed as well. in User Table Email field is indexed.

Now, this query take < 1 sec which is fine to have, but now client want to find user whose' email ids start with specific letter, like `a` and `b`. As soon as I add that to query, it starts taking about 50-60 seconds. I create Index on Email field which is not unique, and new query looks like

```
Select * from tblretailerusers where (company_id=169 or company_id in (select id from tblretailercompany where multi_ret_id='169')) and  ( id in (Select contact_person_1 from tbllocations where status=1 and (retailer_comp_id=169 or retailer_comp_id in (select id from tblretailercompany where multi_ret_id='169')))  OR      id in(Select contact_person_2 from tbllocations where status=1 and (retailer_comp_id=169 or retailer_comp_id in (select id from tblretailercompany where multi_ret_id='169'))) ) and (last_login is not null ) and email  REGEXP '^A|^B'
```

I try to use Explain, in both version of query and the interesting fact I notice is that in Primary table row it do not show any value for `possible_key` where as we are using Primary key `id` search in User table as well as I have Index on Email field too. Here is Explain of query:

[image]

I try to recreate index, current I have index that use ID, CompanyID and Email in one index other than primary key in user table. I also create Index on Company Tables, but nothing speeds it up. User Table is MyISAM.

My another question is, how can I skip Sub Query for Child Company Search, as you can see it was used thrice in above query.

**EDIT**: The reason I am using the REGEXP in my query is that when I try the `Like 'A%'` it was even slow with that option.

**Edit** I just test with `last_login is null` instead of `last_login is not null`, and results take less than 5 seconds. Aren't Null or Not Null similar?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the RegEx:

```
and email  REGEXP '^A|^B'
```

...try a simple LIKE:

```
and (email like 'A%' or email like 'B%')
```

Regular Expressions are a bit of heavy for this rather small comparison. Like will probably be far faster. Also, I wouldn't expect the optimiser to try to decode what the regexp is trying to do. With a Like, however, it knows and will probably use the index you've set up.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I choose `regexp` after `Like %` take even more time for work.